# React-hooks popup context - how to?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I made a react popup context, where you with popupPush function can push new messages that will shows one after another with some delay. Also you can hide current popup to see next one by clicking on it. Everything works fine, except if you push few popups at the same time, only the latest will show up:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    popupPush({ text: x++ })
    popupPush({ text: x++ })
    popupPush({ text: x++ })

    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [])
```

How can i fix this? Or maybe my whole concept is not the best one?

[Codesandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-fire-jk2gh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 0):

After some struggles with reunderstanding of correct functions and useEffect usage with react hooks, i came up with working solution:

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-9cr01?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Mostly useCallback hook is what i was needed. It's was unexpected for me, that wrapping function in it don't trigger unnessesary rerenders.